# Opening files with a "wildcard" in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a directory set up like this:

```
content/
content/file1-helloworld.txt
content/file2myproject.txt
content/file3_howareyou.txt
```

And in python I have the following:

```
file = open("content/FILE_NAME.txt", "r")
print (file.read())
```

I would like to reference the files with a wildcard. So I can open `"file1-helloworld.txt"` by asking for `file1(wildcard)` or something similar.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? "or something similar" is a very vague way of asking. What have you tried, and where are you stuck?

Comment: Have you looked at the `glob` module?

Comment: That's the first I found... Obviously you don't need to  use recursion